# Use ._where to select multiple attribute values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I am using a simple AngularJS code as below:

```
$scope.ActiveProduct= _.where(result, {"Active":1});
```

Now, I have another attribute within **'result'** which is *"ForEStore"* which is either a 0 or 1, and I would like to add only those objects within result into my `$scope.ActiveProduct` that have *Active = 1* and *ForEstore = 1*.

What would be the best approach to do this ?

Comment: Are you looking for `_.where(result, {Active: 1, ForEstore: 1});`?

Comment: Thanks, was a silly error on my part!